# Find Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x} $ and $\mathbf{a}$ are in R$^3$ and $\mathbf{a}$ is a fixed or constant vector. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A.

Comment: How do $b$ and $x$ relate?

Comment: Do you mean $Ax=a\times x$?

Comment: I changed my question. Yes, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you meant $A\vec{x} = \vec{a}\times\vec{x}$ (not $A\vec{b} = \vec{a}\times\vec{x}$). Here's a hint: what do you know about $\vec{a}\times\vec{x}$ with regards to $\vec{x}$ (geometrically)?

---

(I'm going to assume that $\vec{a}\neq \vec{0}$ since otherwise $A$ is the zero matrix which is kind of silly for the purposes of eigenvalues/eigenvectors.) We can view $\vec{a}\times\vec{x}$ as the matrix product

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\ a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\ -a_2 & a_1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{array}\right).$$

You can see this since $\vec{a}\times\vec{x} = (a_2 x_3 - a_3 x_2, a_3 x_1 - a_1 x_3, a_1 x_2 - a_2 x_1)$ and the matrix product above works out exactly the same. Using the usual approach, we want to solve

$$A\vec{x}= \lambda\vec{x}.$$

i.e. we want to solve

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr} -\lambda & -a_3 & a_2 \\ a_3 & -\lambda & -a_1 \\ -a_2 & a_1 & -\lambda \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right).$$

Naturally we want $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ so that we *can* have eigenvalues and eigenvectors. If we expand the determinant of the above what we get is

$$0 = -\lambda\left|\begin{array}{rr} -\lambda & -a_1 \\ a_1 & -\lambda\end{array}\right| + a_3\left|\begin{array}{rr} a_3 & -a_1 \\ -a_2 & -\lambda\end{array}\right| + a_2\left|\begin{array}{rr} a_3 & -\lambda \\ -a_2 & a_1\end{array}\right|.$$

Working this out further we have

$$0 =-\lambda(\lambda^2 + a_1^2) - a_3(a_3\lambda+a_1a_2) + a_2(a_1a_3-a_2\lambda)$$

which becomes

$$0 = -\lambda^3 -a_1^2\lambda - a_3^2\lambda - a_1a_2a_3 + a_1a_2a_3 -a_2^2\lambda = -\lambda^3 - (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)\lambda.$$

Doing some factoring we get

$$0 = \lambda(\lambda^2 + a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2).$$

Since $\vec{a}\neq \vec{0}$, $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2 > 0$ so we cannot have that $\lambda^2 = -a_1^2-a_2^2-a_3^2$. Thus the only choice is $\lambda = 0$. I'll leave it to you to figure out what the eigenvectors are.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I do know the answer to this specific problem but I'm wondering if there's any way to solve it systematically like how we solve eigenvectors and eigenvalues for matrices with real numbers.

Comment: Oh sure. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer now.

Comment: you use A as a matrix with 0 as values for the diagonal. And the values for rest of the matrix are arbitrary. To tackle this kind of problems, can A just be an arbitrary matrix as long as it's convenient for me the solve the problem?

Comment: No it can't. It *must* be of the form I stipulated, otherwise $A\vec{x}$ **will not** agree with $\vec{a}\times\vec{x}$.

Comment: Nevermind, yea I understand now. I don't know why I asked that question. Thanks for your response!

Comment: No problem. Asking questions helps clear up issues in understanding. I'm happy to help :)